# Redirect does not work when inside a flash application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

In my rails controller, I have a show and save action.  The show is for showing the flash application.  The save is for saving the flash application.  When the flash application calls the rails save action I would like it to redirect to a new view in the rails app and no longer be inside the flash application.

I have a redirect_to some_path in the save action.  The server log shows a successful redirect to some_path, however, for the user there is no redirect and they are still stuck inside the flash application.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting the request from flash which won't do you any good.

Instead, let flash do the redirecting on success of the save.